# Rails 'unsafe redirect' from strange curl request

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting occasional errors of this type in production and staging:

`Unsafe redirect to "https://${ip}:${port}/businesses/new", pass allow_other_host: true to redirect anyway.`

It is being caused by Curl requests from a random IP:

```
User-Agent: "curl/7.64.1"
Accept: "*/*"
Host: "${ip}:${port}"
Version: "HTTP/1.1"
```

I do not get it with any other URLs processed within the app.

When I try the same curl request in development I get this (which is correct):

`Rails - [ActionDispatch::HostAuthorization::DefaultResponseApp] Blocked host: "${ip}:${port}"`

I cannot find where the difference is that makes this throw an exception in production.

Any insights on this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: what is this `"${}"` interpolation syntax? Ruby uses `"#{}"`.

Comment: Oh gosh, you are right! Embarrassing...I completely missed that. I will update the question. :-)